# is it possible to specify a region/locale for google custom search engine?

Tags: google-custom-search

I want to use the Google Custom Search API (or custom search engine directly) in the following manner--

(1) I want to get the set of results for a search term for Google UK(This should return results that are returned by a regular search on Google.co.uk- Google UK)

(2) I want to get the results for a search on Google.co.in(Google India)

Is it possible to do the above, either directly while creating a custom search engine, or through the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. Specifiy the parameter `googlehost` in your query. Example: `&googlehost=google.de` or whatever country you want.

Comment: It's now `gl` not `googlehost` I think (not quite 10 years later :) )

Answer (score -1):

It is in the settings, can change from the Control Panel.